# Parsing JSON using GSON ignores the field object

Tags: java, json, list, parsing, gson

As a result of the API request, the following line is received:

```json
[{
   "inn":"7708503727",
   "ogrn":"1037739877295",
   "updateDate":"2021-11-10",
   "focusHref": "...", 
   "fssp":[{
      "officialNum":"855189"
   }]
}]
```

[image]

next , using Gson , I write:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

List<FsspDTO> element_3 = gson.fromJson(stringJSON.get(2),
new TypeToken<List<FsspDTO>>() {}.getType());
```

when creating a java object , not all fields are filled in correctly .The required field **"fssp"** returns null , although it should be filled in

My Class:

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class FsspDTO {

    /**
     * ИНН(ИП)
     * 
     */
   @SerializedName("inn")
    @Expose
    private String inn;
    /**
     * ОГРН(ИП)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("ogrn")
    @Expose
    private String ogrn;
    /**
     * Ссылка на карточку юридического лица (ИП) в Контур.Фокусе (для работы требуется подписка на Контур.Фокус и дополнительная авторизация)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("focusHref")
    @Expose
    private String focusHref;


    @SerializedName("updateDate")
    @Expose
    private String updateDate;


    /**
     * Исполнительные производства
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("fssp")
    @Expose
    private List<Fssp> fssp = null;
```

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Fssp {

    /**
     * Номер исполнительного производства (если известен)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("officialNum")
    @Expose
    private String officialNum;
    /**
     * Номер сводного исполнительного производства (если известен)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("officialAggregatedNum")
    @Expose
    private String officialAggregatedNum;
    @SerializedName("startDate")
    @Expose
    private String startDate;
    /**
     * Сумма в рублях (если известна)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("sum")
    @Expose
    private Double sum;
    /**
     * Предмет (если известен)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("topic")
    @Expose
    private String topic;
    /**
     * Описание исполнительного документа
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("executoryDocument")
    @Expose
    private String executoryDocument;
    /**
     * Номер исполнительного документа
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("executoryDocumentNumber")
    @Expose
    private String executoryDocumentNumber;
    @SerializedName("executoryDocumentDate")
    @Expose
    private String executoryDocumentDate;
    /**
     * Наименование должника (если известен)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("debtorName")
    @Expose
    private String debtorName;
    /**
     * Адрес должника (если известен)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("debtorAddress")
    @Expose
    private String debtorAddress;
    /**
     * Исполнительное производство возвращено взыскателю по причине отсутствия имущества и т.п.
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("returnedToClaimer")
    @Expose
    private Boolean returnedToClaimer;
    /**
     * Окончено в связи с банкротством
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("cancelledBecauseOfBancruptcy")
    @Expose
    private Boolean cancelledBecauseOfBancruptcy;
    /**
     * Окончено в связи с ликвидацией
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("cancelledBecauseOfDissolvement")
    @Expose
    private Boolean cancelledBecauseOfDissolvement;
    @SerializedName("cancelDate")
    @Expose
    private String cancelDate;
    /**
     * Отдел судебных приставов
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("bailiffDepartment")
    @Expose
    private String bailiffDepartment;
    /**
     * Адрес отдела судебных приставов
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("bailiffDepartmentAddress")
    @Expose
    private String bailiffDepartmentAddress;

    /**
```

why is the fssp field not parsed, how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `private List<Fssp> fssp = new ArrayList<>();` instead? I am not that acquainted with Gson but I think it is worth the try. Additionally, you should prefer empty Lists to null Lists. This will most likely reduce your NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Could you please reduce this to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide it (for example in a GitHub repository)? Then it would be easier to find out what is causing this issue.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I figured out the reason, the model for display was not entirely correct

Comment: Can you please add the solution in an answer and accept it or delete the question? Thanks! ;)